# Momentum operator acting on state

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, momentum, hilbert-space

$\vec{P}=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^2}\vec{p}a_\vec{p}^{\dagger}a_\vec{p}$ is the total momentum operator.

How does this operator act on the state $\lvert\vec{p}\rangle=a_\vec{p}^\dagger \lvert0\rangle$?

Note: I know that this should give $P \lvert \vec{p} \rangle = \vec{p} \lvert \vec{p}\rangle$, but I don't see how this should follow.

Comment: Ah, yes! I tried to search this, but don't know why I couldn't find it... This is exactly the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

Use the anticommutation relations and be careful with what you call $\vec{p}$ .